# Transferring IF into WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following works

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Users') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #Users 
END;

CREATE TABLE #Users(UserAccountKey INT);

IF @Period IN ('Overall', 'Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4') 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #Users
      SELECT UserAccountKey
      FROM XXX c
      WHERE c.Name NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'J', 'Q')
      GROUP BY UserAccountKey
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #Users
      SELECT UserAccountKey
      FROM XXX c
      WHERE c.Name NOT IN ('X', 'Y')
      GROUP BY UserAccountKey;
END;
```

Is it possible to shorten this to a single sql statement? Can the `IF` condition be transferred to the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @marc_s cheers a lot tidier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to translate the `if` to a single condition. I believe this will provide the same result:

```
   INSERT INTO #Users
      SELECT UserAccountKey
      FROM XXX c
      WHERE (@Period NOT IN ('Overall', 'Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4')
             and c.Name NOT IN ('X', 'Y'))
         or (@Period IN ('Overall', 'Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4')
            and c.Name NOT IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'J', 'Q'))
      GROUP BY UserAccountKey
```

---

This has been bothering me, because I think it should be able to be simplified, but I couldn't figure out how. My original answer was the same as @Pirion's, but I changed it because I realized it would not be equivalent to the original script. Below is a simplified script that I think provides the same functionality as my earlier answer:

```
   INSERT INTO #Users
      SELECT UserAccountKey
      FROM XXX c
      WHERE not (c.Name IN ('X', 'Y')
                 or (@Period IN ('Overall', 'Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4')
                     and c.Name IN ('Z', 'J', 'Q'))
      GROUP BY UserAccountKey
```

Comment: I've used this version; @Pirion 's version is cleverer but this version will be less thinking on my part if I have to re-visit the script in the future

Answer (score 3):

Can simplfy a litle more:

```
  INSERT INTO #Users
  SELECT UserAccountKey
  FROM XXX c
  WHERE c.Name NOT IN ('X', 'Y')
        OR (@Period IN ('Overall', 'Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4')
             AND c.Name NOT IN ('Z', 'J', 'Q'))
  GROUP BY UserAccountKey
```

Comment: Possible you need use OR instead of first AND.

Comment: Definitely shorter but @Allan solution is more readable - for me at least - my Boolean logic isn't always that sharp.

Comment: This would work if the operators on `name` were `in`. However, because it uses `not in`, the results will be different than the original query. Take, for instance, a situation where `Name = 'Z'` and `@Period = 'Other'`. This situation will satisfy the first half of the `or`, so the row will be inserted. It wouldn't in the original script.

Comment: If period = Other, then it would drop down to the ELSE clause and name = Z is not in X or Y, so it would insert in the original query. Sorry - I don't agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO #Users
SELECT userAccountKey
FROM XXX c
WHERE ( c.Name NOT IN ('X','Y','Z','J','Q')
AND @Period IN ('Overall','Week1','Week2','Week3','Week4'))

OR
(
c.Name NOT IN ('X','Y')
AND @Period NOT IN ('Overall','Week1','Week2','Week3','Week4')
)
GROUP BY UserAccountKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO #Users
SELECT userAccountKey
FROM XXX c
WHERE c.Name NOT IN ('X','Y','Z','J','Q')
AND @Period IN ('Overall','Week1','Week2','Week3','Week4')
GROUP BY UserAccountKey

INSERT INTO #Users
SELECT UserAccountKey
FROM xxx C
WHERE c.Name NOT IN ('X','Y')
AND @Period NOT IN ('Overall','Week1','Week2','Week3','Week4')
GROUP BY UserAccountKey
```

Comment: ...slight misunderstanding: I want to narrow it down to one statement ...see other answers